# Task scheduler not executing argument

Tags: windows-7, scheduled-tasks, tasks, kodi

I am trying to run a program called the renamer that helps to move and rename files for my XBMC setup as a scheduled task (Win7 x64 HyperV VM on Domain).

My current process is to run the program manually via a shortcut, which has an argument (`-fetch`) added.

[image: Shortcut Screenshot]

I would like to automate this action via a scheduled task, but when run from task, nothing happens.

[image: Task Screenshot1]

The task shows as complete, with status `0x1`, but nothing was actually processed.

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you in advance for the help, let me know what additional information is required.